# How to catch invalid input in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can the following logic be implemented in javascript:

According to the description of R-rated films: Children under 17 require an accompanying parent or adult guardian (age 21 or older) and adults 25 years and under must show ID. And children under the age of 6 are not allowed in after 6:00pm.

Deadpool is an R-rated movie.

Write a JavaScript function named canIWatch that will take age as a parameter.

If the age is less than 6, return You are not allowed to watch Deadpool after 6.00pm.

If the age is 6 or more but less than 17, return You must be accompanied by a guardian who is 21 or older.

If the age is 17 or more but less than 25, return You are allowed to watch Deadpool, right after you show some ID.

If the age is 25 or greater, return Yay! You can watch Deadpool with no strings attached!.

If the age is invalid, return Invalid age.

I have written the following code but still can't pass the test, what am I doing wrong?

```
function canIWatch(age){
  if(age<6){
    return 'You are not allowed to watch Deadpool after 6.00pm.';
  }
  else if(age>=6 && age<17){
    return 'You must be accompanied by a guardian who is 21 or older.';
  }
  else if(age>=17 && age<25){
    return 'You are allowed to watch Deadpool, right after you show some         ID.';
  }
  else if(age>=25){
    return 'Yay! You can watch Deadpool with no strings attached!';
  }
  else if(!age){
    return 'Invalid age.';
  }
}
```

I am getting an error :
canIWatch tests should return an appropriate message if provided age is invalid

Expected 'You are not allowed to watch Deadpool after 6.00pm.' to equal 'Invalid age.'.

Comment: For on thing re: your logic, you don't have an else block, so it is possible that the function could return nothing at all (i.e. if none of your if conditions evaluate to true)

Comment: @EatPeanutButter not if all other cases are accounted for, which they appear to be. Even if age doesn't exist it will return 'invalid age'.

To answer the question though: what IS an invalid age? One that is simply not a number?

Comment: Remove `else` at `else..if`

Comment: @zfrisch an invalid age could be anything which is not a number or a negative number.

Comment: @guest271314 I have removed the else but nothing seems to change

Comment: @zfrisch Always account for contingencies you don't expect.  The user will always find some way to short-circuit what you think is air-tight logic

Comment: You can use jquery.validate library for validation.

Comment: @HamzaBaig Needs more jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Remove `else` at `else..if`, include `isNaN` check for invalid age.

```js
function canIWatch(age) {
  if (!age || isNaN(age) || !isNaN(age) && age <= 0) {
    return 'Invalid age.';
  }
  if (age < 6) {
    return 'You are not allowed to watch Deadpool after 6.00pm.';
  }
  if (age >= 6 && age < 17) {
    return 'You must be accompanied by a guardian who is 21 or older.';
  }
  if (age >= 17 && age < 25) {
    return 'You are allowed to watch Deadpool, right after you show some         ID.';
  }
  if (age >= 25) {
    return 'Yay! You can watch Deadpool with no strings attached!';
  }
}

[5, 6, 16, 17, 25, void 0, null, -7, 0].forEach(function(age) {
  console.log(canIWatch(age))
});
```

Comment: This will not work for zero age. Also this check will allow decimal age which I think is not totally correct.

Comment: What do you mean by "zero age"?

Comment: When age equals to zero. For example, a child.

Comment: An age cannot be equal to zero

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to add a check to ensure age is a number:

```
function canIWatch(age){
  if (typeof age !== 'number' || age < 0 || age % 1 > 0) {
    return 'Invalid age.';
  }

  if(age<6){
    return 'You are not allowed to watch Deadpool after 6.00pm.';
  }
  else if(age>=6 && age<17){
    return 'You must be accompanied by a guardian who is 21 or older.';
  }
  else if(age>=17 && age<25){
    return 'You are allowed to watch Deadpool, right after you show some         ID.';
  }
  else if(age>=25){
    return 'Yay! You can watch Deadpool with no strings attached!';
  }
}
```

Here I check if type of number is age and if age isn't decimal number.

Also note: you may not write `else if` each time if you every statement if a return-only statement.

So I have rewritten your code like this:

```
function canIWatch(age){
  if (typeof age !== 'number' || age < 0 || age % 1 > 0) {
    return 'Invalid age.';
  }

  if(age<6){
    return 'You are not allowed to watch Deadpool after 6.00pm.';
  }

  if(age>=6 && age<17){
    return 'You must be accompanied by a guardian who is 21 or older.';
  }

  if(age>=17 && age<25){
    return 'You are allowed to watch Deadpool, right after you show some         ID.';
  }

  if(age>=25){
    return 'Yay! You can watch Deadpool with no strings attached!';
  }
}
```

Also I have formatted your code.

So final version is:

```
function canIWatch(age) {
  if (typeof age !== 'number' || age < 0 || age % 1 > 0) {
    return 'Invalid age.';
  }

  if (age < 6) {
    return 'You are not allowed to watch Deadpool after 6.00pm.';
  }

  if (age >= 6 && age < 17) {
    return 'You must be accompanied by a guardian who is 21 or older.';
  }

  if (age >= 17 && age < 25) {
    return 'You are allowed to watch Deadpool, right after you show some         ID.';
  }

  if (age >= 25) {
    return 'Yay! You can watch Deadpool with no strings attached!';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work just fine. I just removed the else if condition at the end.

```js
function canIWatch(age){
  if(age<6){
    return 'You are not allowed to watch Deadpool after 6.00pm.';
  }
  else if(age>=6 && age<17){
    return 'You must be accompanied by a guardian who is 21 or older.';
  }
  else if(age>=17 && age<25){
    return 'You are allowed to watch Deadpool, right after you show some         ID.';
  }
  else if(age>=25){
    return 'Yay! You can watch Deadpool with no strings attached!';
  }
  else {
    return 'Invalid age.';
  }
}

console.log(canIWatch(4));
console.log(canIWatch(10));
console.log(canIWatch(22));
console.log(canIWatch(29));
console.log(canIWatch("invalid type"));
```

Answer (score -1):

I would put as your last statement:

```
else (age === undefined) {
 return "Invalid age";
}
```

Comment: also you shouldn't use else statement if you have a test case as well